# Changing Button Color without changing the shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout

When i say

```
 button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

the button shape changes to rectangle from default shape. I want to change the button color without affecting its original shape. Please help me.

Comment: have you take default button ?

Comment: Your button is actually rectangle shape, cornered drawable just makes it look like it is not a rectangle at all.

Comment: Are you setting any image as background of button??

Comment: But it affects the whole layout. I created an event for a button. If the button is pressed, the color has to be changed. It happened. But the layout format, the other buttons alignment changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you change the default background of your button the shape is going to change as the default shape is rectangle and the default background is a shape drawable with rounded corners. If you use any other background this rounded corner effect is lost.

You can achieve the same effect with any color or shape if you use a shape drawable as the background. 
 Here is how you can achieve this:

1. Create a shape drawable.
2. Use this drawable as the button's background.

sample code for shape drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid
        android:color="#f8f8f8"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"/>
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#aeaeae"/>
</shape>
```

If you want to have a button with a selector then use this xml as the background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape >
            <solid
                android:color="#ff0000" />
            <stroke 
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape >
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff2727"
                android:endColor="#890000"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#620000" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>        
    </item>
</selector>
```

This is a selector xml with items as the different shape drawables. If the button is pressed that is the button's state is **state_pressed** then the top shape drawable is used else the bottom shape drawable is used.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Its not working for me. if i set the background color at run time the shape changed to rectangle.

Comment: @Lakshmanan the above code if for using the shape drawable thorugh xml. If after setting the background in the xml you change the background through code the previous effect(background) will be overridden.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a solution that worked for me, that contrary to the accepted solution will allow you to change the color dynamically:

```
myButton = (ImageButton)myView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
Drawable roundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button);
roundDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Mode.SRC_ATOP);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(roundDrawable);
} else {
    myButton.setBackground(roundDrawable);
}
```

XML of the "round_button" drawable I used, as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#4db6ac"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Yoann Hercouet. This should be marked as accepted answer since this is really what was asked in the question.

Comment: you can directly set the color filter on the background without having to get the drawable again from the resources like this
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(<color>, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
however this answer is more correct than the accepted one

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem just a few minutes ago.
Using `android:backgroundTint` property in XML of your layout file instead will solve the issue.
The button will retain it's original shape, also the ripple effect won't be lost.

The XML should look something like:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196f3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use color object by default the android system uses paint object to fill the button
and the paint object can fill only the rectangle,circles  shapes rather than the curves
If you really want to represent a button with color and curve shape use custom view (canvas)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom buttons.

check the below link for help  :

http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

Check with this in your layout.xml

android:background="*****"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - changing at run-time/ dynamically. For example, when the button is clicked, the colour changes, but it's shape needs to stay the same.

First, you need to define in xml the button:

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="Change Colour but keep shape, please" />
```

You will see above it calls `buttonshape`, so in your `drawable` folder:

(It's a rectangle, grey, with a dark grey border of `1dp`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#D3D3D3" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#aeaeae" />
</shape>
```

Now a new `xml` file in `drawable` folder, `buttonpressed.xml`, for the button pressed state. The colour will be green, everything else the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#2AB40E" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#aeaeae" />
</shape>
```

Now, on button click in our activity:

```
 private void myButton() {

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//              keep the slightly rounded shape, when the button is pressed
                myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpressed);

etc..etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but for future seekers, this worked for me...

In drawable the button shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

In my layout.xml for the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonOrange"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

With the `android:backgroundTint`, the Buttons get an orange Color when the activity is started.

In my Activity, I change the button color with only one line:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using "setBackgroundColor" was changing the shape of the View.
I solved it with "setTint"

Comment: method doesn't even exist on my Button - otherwise would have loved that solution!