# Android: Programming custom made button background color, while fitting inside button

Tags: java, android, button, view

I'm trying to change the background color of a button I made to a certain color when toggled and back when untoggled, but when I do the color changes the shape of the button.
Here is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View v){
    if(index < 9)
        GameEngine.getInstance().setNumber(number);
    else if(index == 9)
        GameEngine.getInstance().setNumber(number);
    else if (index == 12) {
        GameEngine.getInstance().draftModeSetter();
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb6c1"));
    }
}
```

And here is the result [before color change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXWJJ.png) and the result [after color change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVjxD.png). You can clearly see the "draft" button gets becomes bigger and a sharper square.

Answer (score 0):

If the background color was set using

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

it can be reset using:

```
btn.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Comment: This was the closest to working, except it just makes the button white when toggled no matter what color or PorterDuff mode I input.

Comment: You can call clearColorFilter() for the same object on which you called setColorFilter(). This method is equivalent to setColorFilter(null), and is arguably more readable than the latter.

Comment: is there a way to change the actual color button to a color I want? The setColorFilter() method just sets it to white when toggled and I can't seem to change it.

Comment: I think your question's answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681895/changing-button-color-without-changing-the-shape-in-android

Comment: no quite, because this is a custom made button inside a class, it's not in XML as a single button, but as a group of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  xml ： shape, selector  like :

### shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/blue_400" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_400" />
</shape>
```

### selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_comm_bt_pressed" 
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_comm_bt_normal" 
      android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

### use

```
 <Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/selector_common_bt"
    ...
 />
```